# Firebase is giving "maxretry" error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We're using Firebase as a backend for our mobile app. Some of our users have sporadically received an error "maxretry" with a transaction writing to a path with single numeric value. We don't have multiple users or connections, nor multiple writes to the same path, as far as I know. What might be causing this?

I have a suspicion that this is caused by using floating point values with many decimal places. This error happened to me locally once and I was able to resolve it by limiting the precision to two decimal places. Can this be it?

-Albert

*Edit:*

Here's the code that is causing this:

```
return fireRef.child(fbPath).transaction(function(originalVal) {
  return func(originalVal, by_value);
}, _.noop, false)
```

where in this case the `func` looks like this:

```
function(originalVal, val) {
  return val + (originalVal || 0);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing code that reproduces this problem, it'll be hard to say more than what the error message already says: there are too many retries of a transaction.

Comment: The function is run like a hundred times until the error occurs. No other calls are done to the same function / the same path (at least as far as I know). The `originalVal` was something like `57.39999999999998` and val something like `1.01`.

Comment: Given that Firebase transactions are run using a compare-and-swap, the floating point operand is likely the cause of this problem. If that is the case, the solution is to not use floating point, but instead use a discrete value and a multiplier of that, i.e. `5740` for `57.40`

Comment: That sounds quite overkill to have a multiplier and the value itself for each value transaction is conducted. Don't you think just storing with a precision of, say, two decimal places would be enough?

Comment: I suggest a fixed multiplier in that case. It's quite common when dealing with money to store everything in "cents". I'm not saying it's the best way (because others may disagree), but I guarantee you that it's common. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem persisted even after limiting precision to 2 decimals (getting `maxretry` error every once in a while).

It looks like when updating a value using Firebase transactions floating point type should not be used at all.

I moved to using integers and haven't had the problem anymore.

Comment: While this works, but there is no firebase documentation showing that decimal points should not be used for transactions. But I have also seen this error when using transactions with decimal points. This happens randomly. But at this point, where I have a number `63.99999999999999`, it's not working any more. I have changed the number to `64` and thid has started working again. @Firebase team should clarify this.